# How do I get.ElementByTagName of 3rd div diside of 2nd div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I'm trying to reach an elemnt by using get.ElementByTagName and javascript. I dont want to use class and id. How can I reach 3rd div iside of 2nd div?

```
<div></div>
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div>Here</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: what you tried..?

Comment: jQuery / javascript, as long as it work

Comment: I tried something like that document.querySelector("div div, div div div").appendChild(divParty);

Answer (score 5):

You can use document.querySelector with nth-child

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)'))
```

```html
<div></div>
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div>Here</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Note that I selected the second child because that's the one with "Here" in it. If you want to target the empty one after it, use `nth-child(3)` instead...

---

Just as a sidenote

> I dont want to use class and id

That's a very bad idea, left alone because it would be faster to select the elements you want to target, and it's also much easier to select them, based on a "correctly built" html. The normal way would be to give your elements classes and / or ids (also because of styling reasons to attach the correct css to them)

Comment: Should it not be `'div > div:nth-child(3)'` according to the question?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that's a typo as the "Here" is in the second, other than that you#re right @RohitSharma

Comment: This will fail if some other divs also has two/three children.

Comment: Updated the answer to select the element more specifically @saibbyweb

Comment: Sure, you can do that @MarchewkaPL. Your code however doesn't contain that element in the question

Comment: That's not a very constructive feedback @saibbyweb. What doesn't work in your oppinion? Did you try the snippet?

Comment: No it doesn't. In addition, document.querySelector always selects the first found element only. @saibbyweb

Comment: @bambam did you check the pen?

Comment: @bambam it logs two entries "Here" and "Also here" ? "Also here" is inside the fifth main div ?

Comment: That's not possible. Please read the spec for querySelector and you'll see it's not possible that it logs two elements @saibbyweb

Comment: My bad! Got confused with codepen's output widow with console window :/

Comment: No problem :-) @saibbyweb